# Compiling java code within .net

Tags: java, .net, compilation

I need to compile java code from a .net application. I tried running a cmd process and giving arguments but it didn't work. Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Showing your code thus far would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, why are you compiling Java with .NET?

Comment: javac *can* be executed from another program, even .Net. There probably is a bug in your code.

Comment: @jrummell I'm making a simple source code editor for Java. I tried to do it this way: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C

Comment: "I'm making a simple source code editor for Java." What will it do that the many free, open source and working editors and IDEs don't do already?

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled java files for a Mono For Android project in Visual Studio, basically you still need to use javac, but you can create a script to do this for you.

**Disclaimer:** This is a simple script that works for simple applications, it doesn't replace a dedicated Java build system such as ANT. My example uses powershell, but the same concept could be applied using regular batch files.

**Our prebuild step for the library calls a powershell script:**

```
powershell.exe -noprofile C:\mypath\Java\buildj.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

**And here is a stripped down example of a powershell script that does the javac compile:**

```
if (Get-Command javac -errorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Get-Childitem C:\mypath\Java\JBin -include *.class -recurse | foreach ($_) {Remove-Item $_.fullname}

    $JavaList = Get-Content C:\filelist.txt

    foreach ($file in $JavaList) {
        $command = "javac C:\mypath\Java\JBin " + $file
        Write-Host $command
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }

}
else {
    throw "javac could not be located. Check your PATH"
}
```

Inside filelist.txt you need to have a list of your java files with the full path.